# How to use the GROUP BY statement twice in a single SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT CourseId, DateOfCourseCompletion, COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeId) FROM tblTestsTakenByEmployee ttbe
    INNER JOIN tblCoursesTakenByEmployee ctbe USING (ctbe.EmployeeId)
    WHERE ctbe.HasCompletedCourse = 'Y'
    GROUP BY ctbe.CourseId, ctbe.DateOfCourseCompletion, ctbe.EmployeeId
    HAVING AVG(ttbe.GivenMark) > 50
    ORDER BY ctbe.CourseId, ctbe.DateOfCourseCompletion;
```

Currently, this finds the average mark of a single employee who has an average mark on a course done on a certain date greater than 50, calculated across the various tests they have done (a course can have multiple tests).

However, now I want to count the number of employees with a mark greater than 50 that have completed the same course on the same date. I assume you can't use GROUP BY again, since the statement was already used to group together all the tests an employee has done on a given course. How would I group by this without the use of the GROUP BY statement?

Comment: When a query joins tables, it's very important to prepend each column name with the table name or table alias. It may be obvious to you where each column comes from, but it's not for us.

Comment: The simplest - and most efficient - way is to make your first query a *sub*query. Then in the outer query select from the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery - outer query approach, something like this (not tested):

```
select courseid, dateofcoursecompletion, count(employeeid) as employee_count
from   (
         select courseid, dateofcoursecompletion, employeeid
         from   tblteststakenbyemployee ttbe
                inner join tblcoursestakenbyemployee ctbe using (employeeid)
         where  ctbe.hascompletedcourse = 'Y'
         group  by courseid, dateofcoursecompletion, employeeid
         having avg(givenmark) > 50
       )
group  by courseid, dateofcoursecompletion
order  by courseid, dateofcoursecompletion
;
```

Note that you don't need **distinct** in the count of employees. The aggregation in the subquery produces distinct triples of `(courseid, dateofcompletion, employeeid)`, so in the outer query, in each group by `(courseid, dateofcompletion)` the employee id's are already distinct.